# Prevent a user from accessing the internet, except for certain websites

Tags: 12.10, iptables

I'm trying to prevent a specific user from receiving traffic from any sites except specific sites on a whitelist. The easiest way to do this seems to be with iptables, but I haven't been able to get my iptables settings to work - the browser says it can't resolve the DNS address. I'm running Ubuntu 12.10.

Here is my iptables file so far:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.12 on Sat Jul 13 07:41:12 2013
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [3137:3823422]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1877:121508]
-A INPUT -s [[SPECIFIC IP]] -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT  #
-A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT  # THESE 3 LINES ARE AN ATTEMPT TO GET DNS TO WORK
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 953 -j ACCEPT # 
-A INPUT -m owner --uid-owner 1000 -j DROP  # disable all other packets for that user
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jul 13 07:41:12 2013
```

That file is loaded on startup using `sudo iptables-restore < /etc/iptables_rules`, which works. No SSHing is needed anywhere.

The immediate problem is that DNS lookups fail for that user. I'm probably doing something completely wrong, I don't know iptables well.

Thanks for all help! :)

Comment: There's no need to specify INPUT rules for DNS or websites - you are not running a DNS server on this machine, nor are you running these websites yourself, right? Instead, use OUTPUT rules here as I assume you're about to filter/allow data *from* this host *to another* (=output).

Comment: Perhaps you want to try another approach: 1) set up your own recursive DNS resolver server. 2) Set up your client host to change all OUTPUT traffic for uid 1000 about DNS to redirect it to that DNS server host. 2) Set up a proxy server filtering the websites (using a regular DNS server). 3) Have the DNS point all sites to your proxy server. 4) Block all other traffic except to your proxy/DNS hosts for uid 1000.

Comment: @gertvdijk Thanks for the help! Everything works now, except that traffic from the allowed IPs is really slow for some reason. (Updated the iptables file above.)

Comment: Actually nevermind, internet is back up to speed again, so this problem is completely solved. Thanks!

Comment: Wait a minute... we don't change the questions to provide the solution on Ask Ubuntu. Please revert your edits (rollback) and post an answer as an answer (scroll below to "Your answer"). It's perfectly fine to answer your own questions here, it's [how this site works](http://askubuntu.com/about).

Comment: Alright, doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the file like this fixed everything:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.12 on Sat Jul 13 07:41:12 2013
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [3137:3823422]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1877:121508]
-A OUTPUT -d [[SPECIFIC IP]] -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --destination-port 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp --destination-port 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --destination-port 953 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 1000 -j DROP
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jul 13 07:41:12 2013
```

Thanks to gertvdijk for telling me what to change.